# asp.net web application update procedure

Tags: asp.net, deployment

i need to find a good way to update a web application that i  am working on. i dont have access to the production environment. the client wants some kind of exe self-update package that i can send over to him and have him run it to update the app. is that do-able? what is the alternatives. right now i am just compiling the site and send everything over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need a web deployment package. Here's Scott Gu's blog entry on the subject: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/29/vs-2010-web-deployment.aspx